# How to fix System.InvalidOperationException error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to join two tables using Entity Framework but getting  `System.InvalidOperationException` error. The error message is:

> The property 'MasterCompany' is not a navigation property of entity type 'UnitOfMeasure'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.`.

I am not sure why it is throwing it.

**Other Attempts:**

1. I also tried adding `public virtual MasterCompany MasterCompany { get; set; }` in `UnitOfMeasure` but that throws `Invalid column error`.
2. Also added `[Key]` in `MasterCompany` table for `MasterCompanyId`.
3. But both of these changes throws `Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'.` error.

**DAL Models:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
{
  public DbSet<UnitOfMeasure> UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
  public DbSet<MasterCompany> MasterCompany { get; set; }
}

public class UnitOfMeasure : PasBase, IAudit
{
    [Key]
    public long UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public string Standard { get; set; }
    // [ForeignKey("MasterCompanyId")]
    public Int32 MasterCompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string UploadStatus { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MasterCompanyId")]
    public virtual MasterCompany MasterCompany { get; set; }
}

public class MasterCompany:AuditableEntity
{
    public int MasterCompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string TaxId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
private ApplicationDbContext _appContext => (ApplicationDbContext)_context;

public IEnumerable<DAL.Models.UnitOfMeasure> getUnitOfMeasureData()
{
    return _appContext.UnitOfMeasure
        .Include("MasterCompany")
        .Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false || c.IsDeleted == null)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.UnitOfMeasureId)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `MasterCompany` entity property on your `UnitOfMeasure` entity, which should be decorated with the `ForeignKey` attribute and not the `MasterCompanyId` property.

Comment: @Silvermind, In this case, I get `'Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'.`error.

Comment: Then check your database. Obviously that column does not exist. Check for typos. Also the check for `IsDeleted == null` is weird, because the column is not nullable according to your code and you are not using a left join that would justify that.

Comment: @Silvermind You are 100% right. Column name is `IsDelete` and it was `IsDeleted`. Thank you (I should have paid attention to the column name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `MasterCompany` property in the class `UnitOfMeasure`

```
public class UnitOfMeasure : PasBase, IAudit
{
    [Key]
    public long UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public string Standard { get; set; }
    public Int32 MasterCompanyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MasterCompanyId")]
    public MasterCompany MasterCompany { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string UploadStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I get `'Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'.`error.

Comment: Column name was wrong. Actual one is `IsDelete` not `IsDeleted`.